# OAuth2 With Spring Boot Unauthorized (401) Response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have implemented a spring boot application with oauth2. when I am trying to access token by providing clientId and Secret then unauthorized(401) response is returned.

oauth_client_detals table is designed in the oracle database with the following schema and secret column value is stored in BCrypt format.

```
insert into oauth_client_details(client_id,client_secret,web_server_redirect_uri,
scope,accsess_token_validity,refresh_token_validity,resource_id,authorized_grant_types,authorities,
  additional_information,autoapprove) values ('web','{bcrypt}$2y$12$FCIQkEmh7ai/6oP99yNOEuWnKt9OjrGEczCxnEnFGDRSOHumOChQO',
  '','READ,WRITE','900','3600','','password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit','ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER,ROLE_MANAGER','','');
```

### AuthorizationConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServer  extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
               security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()").tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

### SecurityConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider1());
    }

    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider1()
    {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider=new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

### UserDetailsServiceImpl.class

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user= userDAO.findByUserName(username)
                .orElseThrow(()->new UsernameNotFoundException("data not found with "+username));

        return AuthUserDetails.builder(user);
    }

}
```

### AuthUserDetails.class

```
public class AuthUserDetails implements UserDetails{

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private boolean accNonExpired;
    private boolean accNonLocked;
    private boolean credentialNonExpired;
    private boolean active;

    public AuthUserDetails()
    {

    }

    public AuthUserDetails(boolean active, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities, String userName, String password,
            boolean accNonExpired, boolean credentialNonExpired, boolean accNonLocked) {

        this.active = active;
        this.authorities = authorities;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.accNonExpired = accNonExpired;
        this.credentialNonExpired = credentialNonExpired;
        this.accNonLocked = accNonLocked;
    }

    public static UserDetails builder(User user)
    {

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities=new ArrayList<>();

         user.getRoles().forEach(role-> {

                    grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name()));

                    role.getPermissions().forEach(perm->{
                            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(perm.getName().name()));
                    });

                });

         return new AuthUserDetails((user.getActive()==1),grantedAuthorities,user.getUserName(),user.getPassword(),
                 (user.getAccNonExpired()==1), (user.getCredentialNonExpired()==1),(user.getAccNonLocked()==1));

      
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return accNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return accNonLocked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return credentialNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return active;
    }
}
```

### User.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user56",schema = Schema.OAUTH2,uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
        columnNames = "username"
))
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="user_id_gen",sequenceName = Schema.OAUTH2+".user_id_seq",initialValue = 1003,allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "user_id_gen",strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int userId;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "active")
    private int active;
    @Column(name = "acc_non_expired")
    private int accNonExpired;
    @Column(name = "credential_non_expired")
    private int credentialNonExpired;
    @Column(name = "acc_non_locked")
    private int accNonLocked;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "role_user",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName = "user_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id",referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Set<Role> roles;

}
```

### OAuthClient.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "oauth_client_details",schema = Schema.OAUTH2)
@Getter
@Setter
public class OAuthClient {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "client_id")
    private String clientId;
    @Column(name="client_secret")
    private String clientSecret;
    @Column(name = "web_server_redirect_uri")
    private String webServerRedirectUri;
    @Column(name = "scope")
    private String scope;
    @Column(name = "accsess_token_validity")
    private String accessTokenValidity;
    @Column(name = "refresh_token_validity")
    private String refreshTokenValidity;
    @Column(name = "resource_id")
    private String resourceId;
    @Column(name="authorized_grant_types")
    private String authorizedGrantType;
    @Column(name = "authorities")
    private String authorities;
    @Column(name = "additional_information")
    private String additionalInformation;
    @Column(name = "autoapprove")
    private String autoApprove;

}
```

response unauthorized(401) through postman

[image]

### Updated

AuthEntryPoint.class

```
@Component
public class AuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {


        Logger ERROR_LOGGER= LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPoint.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {

        ERROR_LOGGER.error("Unauthorized error : {}",authException.getMessage());

        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,"Error : Unauthorized");

    }
}
```

### Updated 2

when I tried to run the application under the debugging mode then the following error will occur

> FileNotFoundException@769

[image]

Comment: What are the parameters you are sending in your request? What is the `AuthEntryPoint` you are using in your implementation?

Comment: @doctore I am sending grant_type, username, and password as parameters via form-data and I will update AuthEntry point class

Comment: Adapting into my project your code, I have no problem invoking the request (however, my current configuration is quite different, so I cannot be sure about the root cause in your case). Probably debugging your request in detail you will get more information about the problem. I would start with your `UserDetailsServiceImpl` to be sure the `username` trying to find is the provided in the parameter `username`, not `web`

Comment: On the other hand, not sure because you do not mention, but if you are using `spring-security-oauth2` artifact to deal with Spring + Oauth 2. The endpoint to get an access token (or refresh one) is `POST` not `GET` as you use in your attached picture. More information: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenEndpoint.html#postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,%20java.util.Map)

Comment: @doctore yes. it is post request. but I did oauth2 with in-memory at the time it worked and when I passing client-id and secret then method not allowed response is returned. The unauthorized error occurs when I use DAO authentication instead of in-memory.

Comment: @doctore I think the problem is AuthorizationServer does not read client-id and client-secret from the database through the data source. I checked the connection using the data source and it is fine.

Comment: @doctore I don't know a clear idea about that. how AuthorizationServer knows the client-id and client-secret are available in oauth_clients_details table through the data source. In this case, we are not define read this value form this column on that table. it is done by spring security+oauth2.

Comment: The `client_id` and `client_secret` is extracted from the Http request through `BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal` which internally uses `BasicAuthenticationConverter.convert(HttpServletRequest request)`. As you can see in that code, basically gets those ones from `String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");` with Basic Authorization. Include a breakpoint on it to be sure you are receiving expected values: `web` and `********`. Those ones should be included in the Spring principal object and to be accesible in `TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken`

Comment: First be sure what I told you in the above comment. However, give a try removing `and().httpBasic()` of your configuration.

Comment: @doctore tried it (without httpBasic method) but the response is unauthorized

Comment: ok, try to debug the classes and methods I told you. Those ones get the `client_id` and `client_password` from your request (included in your Basic Authentication). About how Spring Oauth get the information from `oauth_client_details` is using the following class: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/client/JdbcClientDetailsService.java

Comment: @doctore I tried to debug but still couldn't;t find the place. I will share my code with the git repo. can you please check it . https://github.com/Benzeman97/oauth2-with-jwt

Comment: Those classes are related with artifact `spring-security-oauth2` but you are using `spring-cloud-starter-oauth2`

Comment: @doctore are you sure about that? anyway, I have added spring-security-oauth2 instead of spring-cloud-starter-oauth2 but the result is unauthorized and in spring-security-oauth2 some classes and annotations are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded you project from [here](https://github.com/Benzeman97/oauth2-with-jwt) and, initially, I only have found some typo in the columns: `accsess_token_validity` and `resource_id`

After that I have added the required tables of your project and include some dummy information. For that reason, I'm pretty sure your problem is related with the `password` values in your `oauth_client_details` and `user56` tables, because only when the stored value did not match with the expected one, I received `401`.

Take into account you have defined two different `BCryptPasswordEncoder` instances:

1. `provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())` for the users included in `user56`.
2. `clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())` for the users included in `oauth_clients_detail`

Once I fixed it and store the expected ones, I achieved the endpoint returned the expected result:

[image: Basic Authentication]
[image: Required parameters and result]

As I told you in previous comments, there several classes will help you to find the cause of the error:

---

**BasicAuthenticationFilter** will get from the request the Basic Auth provided and executes the authentication process.

[image: BasicFilterAuthentication]

---

**BasicAuthenticationConverter** will extract Basic Auth provided from the request really.

[image: BasicAuthenticationConverter]

---

**JbdcClientDetailsService** will get from `oauth_clients_detail` the information related with provided `client_id` in Basic Auth.

[image: JbdcClientDetailsService]

---

The following pictures are the most important to verify if your passwords match. That method will invoke twice: first for `client_id / client_pass` and second for `username / password`.

I have included some useful information in the "debug area"

[image: DaoAuthenticationProviderClientId]
[image: DaoAuthenticationProviderUsername]

Comment: I tried to run the application in the debugging mode then an Error occurs. It is updated under the update2 in the above question

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have found the place where the problem is occurring, When I send the request to the server then unauthorized(401) error occurs with the following message,

> Encoded password does not look like BCrypt

So I have replaced the following code in SecurityConfig.class

```
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

  // replace to

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
```

It works fine but still, I couldn't find why BCrytptPasswordEncoder is not worked even secret values are stored in BCrypt format. Anyway thank you very much @doctore for your answer